# Visual studio 2019 Custom colors overridden

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I have just upgrade from VS2017 to VS2019 and I have my own colors on classes, enums etc. that I would like to be the same in VS2019. I export all my settings, install all the same extension (for example Viasfora, SemanticColorizer) from VS2017 in VS2019, and then import my settings from VS2017.

I open a .cs file and I see my colortheme and 1sec later the colors change to some standard colors.
I have tried the unchecking the "Use enhanced colors for C# and Basic" under options.

And here´s the kicker, the "code preview side-window" shows the right colors...

Anyone got an idea of what this is and how to solve it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from what I have learned so far is that there are more parameters for color customizations in VS19 and there is some name changes that stops the import.

What I did was installing VS theme editor([VS19ThemeEditor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2019ColorThemeEditor))
Changed a bunch off settings in there.

Then I added [SemanticColorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer) and [ViasFora](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomasRestrepo.Viasfora), then went to Tools-->options-->Enviroment-->Font and colors. Changed alot of things there.

And for fun added [ClaudiaIDE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbuchi.ClaudiaIDE)

TL;DR
You cant export from VS17 to VS19 and expect colors to be the same, you need to edit them again.

[image]